# If I want to delete some ascending files in a folder while leaving others in ansible, what would that look like?

Tags: file, ansible

The example is you have a folder with files numbered *files_0.jpg* to *files_10.jpg* in a folder */tmp/folder*.

I'm trying to figure out how to delete *files_0.jpg* to *files_4.jpg* while leaving *files files_5.jpg* to *files_10.jpg*.

For extra points, same scenario, but, I want to delete *files_0.jpg* to *files_4.jpg* and *files_8.jpg* to *files_10.jpg* leaving *files_5.jpg*, *files_6.jpg* and *files_7.jpg*.

I'm trying to figure out how to do this in Ansible and I am stuck at trying to use a regex.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`range()`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-globals.range) function in order to loop over the file sequence you want to delete.

To delete `files_{0..4}.jpg`:

```yaml
- file:
    state: absent
    path: "/tmp/folder/file_{{ item }}.jpg"
  loop: "{{ range(0, 5) }}"
```

To delete `files_{0..4}.jpg` and `files_{8..10}.jpg`:

```yaml
- file:
    state: absent
    path: "/tmp/folder/file_{{ item }}.jpg"
  loop: "{{ range(0, 5) | list + range(8, 11) | list  }}"
```

---

Given the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - file:
        state: absent
        path: "/tmp/folder/file_{{ item }}.jpg"
      loop: "{{ range(0, 5) | list + range(8, 11) | list }}"
```

This would yield:

```
TASK [file] *******************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item=0)
changed: [localhost] => (item=1)
changed: [localhost] => (item=2)
changed: [localhost] => (item=3)
changed: [localhost] => (item=4)
changed: [localhost] => (item=8)
changed: [localhost] => (item=9)
changed: [localhost] => (item=10)
```